# Bootcamp Assist Disappeared after Windows Update

Tags: mac, bootcamp

My windows crashed and I had to reset by re-installing windows.  After it was complete, I lost the ability to access Bootcamp so that I can switch back into the Mac.  I am stuck in Windows!   Anyone know how to help get Bootcamp back so that I can access the Mac?  Everything I find is to re-install BC assistant, but I cannot get into the Mac to do that.

Comment: Have you tried holding the OPTION key while rebooting the Mac? That **should** give you the boot drive selector independent of the OS and allow you to select Mac or Windows

Answer (score 1):

Separate to the Boot Camp Control Panel, you can always **choose your startup disk by holding alt/option on boot**.

1. Shutdown, then hold option/alt and click the power button once, continuing to hold option until the Startup Manager appears.
2. Choose your macOS startup disk to start from macOS this time.
3. Download the support software from Boot Camp Assistant and copy it to an external disk or other shared location between Windows and macOS.
4. Restart your Mac, which will boot into Windows again.
5. Reinstall the Boot Camp support software you downloaded and copied in step 3.

If you want to use Startup Manager in the future, something perhaps useful to know is you can change the default disk from the Startup Manager by holding control while choosing your startup disk.

Comment: If you don't see the option for booting into macOS it is nearly certain that the Windows install destroyed your macOS partition.  I hope you made a backup.

Comment: while tapping power button? really?

Comment: @Ric I meant tapping once vs holding. I've clarified, is that better?